# Get mediaId in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco 7, i am trying to get the Id of a Image on the page. I am using;

```
@Umbraco.Field("myImage")
```

But, it does not return the mediaId. Instead it returns;

```
Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.PublishedMediaCache+DictionaryPublishedContent
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 3 ways:

- `@CurrentPage.myImage`
- `@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage")`
- Using ModelsBuilders you can access it as `@Model.myImage`

The first method should be avoided because Umbraco will be dropping support for Dynamics (see https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Common-Pitfalls/#dynamics).

ModelsBuilder is my preferred way for accessing published content properties as it provides a strongly typed model based on your Document Type. But it requires some setup.  See https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2016/getting-started-with-modelsbuilder/ for a great intro.

The final option is accessing the properties from  `@Model.Content` ([`IPublishedContent`](https://our.umbraco.org/apidocs/csharp/api/Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent.html#Umbraco_Core_Models_IPublishedContent_Properties) and unlike the Dyanamics method, will continue to be supported in the next version of Umbraco.

Comment: Thx for your reply Alex.

Just tried this: @Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage"). This returns excatly the same as the one in my initial post: 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.PublishedMediaCache+DictionaryPublishedContent '

Comment: I can get all other values (text, true/false) in the excat same way without any problems. But the Media Picker always returns the value above, no matter what i do, it seems.

Comment: @brother what version of Umbraco 7 are you using?

Comment: @brother also, are you using any property value converters such as https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-core-property-value-converters?

Comment: version 7.6 is the one i am using

Comment: and nope, not using those

Comment: @brother strange. can you try `@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("myImage")` (without `<int>`) and `@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage").Id`?

Comment: @Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<int>("myImage").Id results in YSOD: 'cannot convert from 'method group' to 'HelperResult'.
@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("myImage") returns the same string as above.

Comment: @brother - did you get this figured out? The options I listed above usually work...

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco 7 you can use @CurrentPage. You just need to use:

```
@CurrentPage.myImage
```

instead of @Umbraco.Field("myImage") and it will return mediaId

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded to version 7.6.12 and there are some updates with the media picker. To use it as you done you should select the obsolete mediapicker in the backoffice otherwise `Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("myImage").Url` should work. If you using the UmbracoHelper, you could write `UmbracoHelper.AssignedContentItem.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>(propertyName, recursive).Url`

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/